# Unable to connect to disk database using SQLite with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

So I am writing an API for my front-end app to save login authentication. For some reason, I am unable to connect to the SQLite database I have made using DB Browser. Every time I try to connect it seems to connect to an in memory database. I have tried doing this mutiple times but have no luck, please help.

Here is the file structure:
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7UtF.png)

Note: the main file is admin-route.js and admin.db

I am currently trying to get it to work using the /admin/register route.

Here is the code:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose()

const admin = require('../admin')

let db = new sqlite.Database('../admin.db', (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
    console.log("Connected to admin database")    
})

// async function openDB() {
//   const db = await sqlite.open('/services/Admin/admin.db', { Promise })
//   const sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Admin(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user TEXT, pass TEXT);'
//   await db.run(sql)
// }

router.get('/admin/login', (req, res) => {
    // const result = db.get('Select * from user', (err, results) => {
    //   console.log(results)
    //   // res.render(results)
    // })
    // console.log("Here is the result " + result)
    // console.log(req.body)
  })
  
router.post('/admin/register', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username
  const password = req.body.password
  console.log(username)
  console.log(password)
  const result = db.get('SELECT * FROM admin', (err, results) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(results)
    }
  })
})
  
router.post('/admin/user', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})


module.exports = router
```

Comment: Error message is: { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: admin
--> in Database#get('SELECT * FROM admin', [Function])

Comment: According to the error message the problem isn't the connection but the fact that you're trying to select from a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: But the table does exist. I believe its connecting to a database in memory? I have checked if the table exists by using DB Browser.

Comment: Do you see `"Connected to admin database"` in the console? Why do you think it's connected to a "database in memory"?

Comment: Yes your right, I just saw another db in the root directory that I didn't look at. I guess Its pointing to the wrong db but I'm pretty sure the file path is correct though?

Comment: So I have removed that db in the root directory and then ran the script again. It says "Connected to admin database" but the table does not exist. I have opened the admin.db using db browser and the table does exist

Comment: I have solved the issue. The path should have been './services/Admin/admin.db' and not '../admin.db'. I guess you can't use '../' when specifying the path of the folder.

Comment: You can absolutely do that but `..` means "go up a level" and afaik the actual path depends on the current file's directory so you need to make sure the path is correct. IIRC the database file will be created if it doesn't exist, so you probably have an empty admin.db file somewhere in your folder tree. Search for it to understand where `../admin.db` ended up pointing.